# In ActiveAndroid, how do I order by primary key?

Tags: android, activeandroid

I read that activeandroid generates ids for every record inserted.

I want to retrieve records from latest created to earliest created.  I know to use orderBy(COL_NAME, DESC), where COL_NAME is the primary key column, but what is that column name?

I know I can create a pseudo primary key:

```
@Column(name = "id", unique = true, onUniqueConflict = Column.ConflictAction.REPLACE)
public long id;
```

and do

```
orderBy("id DESC").execute()
```

but I feel it's wasteful when I could just use the real primary key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Active Android Github Side:

> One important thing to note is that ActiveAndroid creates an id field for your tables. This field is an auto-incrementing primary key.

In your case you could delete your `@Column` and it will work fine.

Source:
https://github.com/pardom/ActiveAndroid/wiki/Creating-your-database-model